# Ionic 3 FormControl Errors not displaying

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

my ionic form does not show if errors exist when an input is performed.

The HTML code looks like

```
<form [formGroup]="LoginForm" (ngSubmit)="loginUser(LoginForm.value)">

<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating >Email</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
  <div *ngIf="!LoginForm.controls.email.valid && LoginForm.controls.email.dirty">
   Please enter a valid email.
  </div>
</ion-item>
```

And the TS file looks like

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
private toast: ToastServiceProvider, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  this.LoginForm = formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(1), Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')])],
    password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])],
  }) }
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is content inside `ion-item` that is not expected, you need to add `item-content` to the tag, so in your case....

```html
<div item-content *ngIf="....">
```

But you really don't want to do it like that, since that will produce the error message right above the input: [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ky5qgs?file=pages/home/home.html)

Instead I would add the error message inside another `ion-item` below your form field:

```html
<ion-item no-lines *ngIf="....">
  <p>Please enter a valid email</p>
</ion-item>
```

That produces a much nicer result: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bzx9bu?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Add a name attribute to each form control.

```
<ion-input type="email" formControlName="email" name="somename"></ion-input>
```